# Match floating point number with regular expression

Tags: regex, neo4j

I am trying to find the floating point numbers in a given range with regular expression in neo4j. For example, return all numbers which are in range 0-5. So the result could be: 1, 1.1, 5.21, 4.45. I am using the regular expression `[0-5]*[.][0-5]*` but it is also returning the result greater than 5, which is not correct. I want to handle the regular expression in a way like it is matching with a string because my database is designed in such a way that a node contains strings, integers and floating point number, all are in form or string. So I want to match floating point values with the regular expression.

Comment: Try `^[0-5][.][0-5]+$`

Comment: Do you want to validate the number, or extract a floating point number, such as from `foo 5.21 bar`?

Comment: To extract a number with optional fraction use this regex: `[0-5](\.[0-9]+)?`. It will return `1.23` for input `foo 1.23 bar`

Comment: Just want to validate the number. These are placed separately, not with strings

Comment: thanks @Thefourthbird. Its working fine

Comment: To validate integers and fractional numbers use this: `^[0-5](\.[0-9]+)?$`. This matches just `1`, as well as `1.23` between `0.0` and `5.9999`. There is also a regex for between `0` and `5` with fractional in between if needed, let me know.

Comment: @PeterThoeny thanks for your answer. solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex to match numbers exactly between `0` and `5` with fractional numbers in between:

```
^(?:[0-4](\.[0-9]+)?|5(\.0+)?)$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - non-capture group start, used for OR

  - `[0-4]` - integer between `0` and `4`
  - `(\.[0-9]+)?` - optional `.` and digits
  - `|` - OR
  - `5` - literal `5`
  - `(\.0+)?` - optional `.` and zeros
- `)` - non-capture group end
- `$` - end of string